# Changing the video upon the changing of the link in YouTube player

Tags: android, youtube-data-api, ytplayerview

I am pasting a link to video in edittext. I want the video to reload when the link is changed and button is clicked after it. The edit text take the http address, splits it accordingly to get the exact link for YouTube player. Each time the address is changed , the address string that is being passed to YouTube player is changed too.

I logged it and it's working fine. But the problem is that when I paste the URL for the first time, it works fine and loads the video, but once the video is loaded and i change the URL and press the button to play video, nothing happens. I guess the playerview is initialized and i cant reinitialize it? Is there a way to reinitialize it?

Here is my code of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
  >
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:hint="Paste the link here"
        />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Play Video"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/search"
        android:id="@+id/play"/>

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtube"
        android:layout_below="@+id/play"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And the code to java file is :

```
public class YoutubeMain extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {
    public static final String API_KEY = "api key";
    public String VIDEO_ID;
    Button playvideo;
    EditText videoid;
    public Boolean clicked;
    YouTubePlayer myoutubeplayer;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.youtube);
        videoid=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.search);
        playvideo=(Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        playvideo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                clicked=true;

                if (videoid.getText().toString().contains("="))
                    {
                        Log.d("Youtube","the id is:"+videoid.getText().toString());
                        int start = videoid.getText().toString().indexOf("=");
                        String suffix = videoid.getText().toString().substring(start + 1);
                        Log.d("Youtube","the id after cropping is: "+suffix);
                        VIDEO_ID=suffix;
                    }
                else
                    {
                        Log.d("Youtube","the id is:"+videoid.getText().toString());
                        int start = videoid.getText().toString().indexOf(".");
                        String suffix = videoid.getText().toString().substring(start + 4);
                        Log.d("Youtube","the id after cropping is: "+suffix);
                        VIDEO_ID=suffix;
                    }
                    Log.d("Youtube","Suffix:" +VIDEO_ID);
                YouTubePlayerView youTubePlayerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.youtube);
                youTubePlayerView.initialize(API_KEY, YoutubeMain.this);

            }


        });
    }


    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Failured to Initialize!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
/** add listeners to YouTubePlayer instance **/
        player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
        player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
/** Start buffering **/
        if (!wasRestored) {
            player.cueVideo(VIDEO_ID);
        }
        Log.d("Youtube","The value of clicked is : "+clicked);

    }
    private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPaused() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onPlaying() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onStopped() {
        }
    };
    private PlayerStateChangeListener playerStateChangeListener = new PlayerStateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAdStarted() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(ErrorReason arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoaded(String arg0) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onLoading() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onVideoEnded() {
        }
        @Override
        public void onVideoStarted() {
        }
    };


}
```

Comment: Why are you create new YouTubePlayer player;on line before onInitializationSuccess ??

Comment: @ArnoldBrown removed it. Sorry my bads, i was just experimenting something and forgot to remove

Comment: Now is it working fine??

Comment: No its not. The problem is still here

Comment: I inserted it in attempts to solve the problem. The problem existed before i tried this

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!!

```
private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;

 @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {
        if(!b){
            startHttp(strUrl, youTubePlayer);
        }
    }

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult errorReason) {
    if (errorReason.isUserRecoverableError()) {
        errorReason.getErrorDialog(this, RECOVERY_REQUEST).show();
    } else {
        String error = String.format(getString(R.string.player_error), errorReason.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this, error, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

private void startHttp(final String strUrl, final YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
     youTubePlayer.cueVideo(strUrl);
}


@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == RECOVERY_REQUEST) {
            // Retry initialization if user performed a recovery action
            getYouTubePlayerProvider().initialize(Config.YOUTUBE_API_KEY, this);
        }
    }

    protected YouTubePlayer.Provider getYouTubePlayerProvider() {
        return youTubePlayerView;
    }
```

Comment: explain this a little bit please

Comment: what is the recovery request?

Comment: just an integer " private static final int RECOVERY_REQUEST = 1;"

Comment: Nothing is happening. The bubtton only works when i close the activity and reopen it.

Comment: I have a model(search youtube by url), if you want ill send or post it